# Getting around "introduces to cycle in the graph" maven exception

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, build

I have module A and module B in my application. Module A has dependency of module B as shown below.

**Module A `pom.xml`**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And now module B needs access to a(one) class defined in module A. I tried doing this by defining a dependency on module A in module B's pom as shown below and I get cyclical exception.

```
  The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between
 `'Vertex{label='A'}' and 'Vertex{label='B'}' introduces to cycle in the graph A --> B --> A
```

**Question**: How can I get around this? I just need access to few classes in Module A from Module B.

**Module B `pom.xml`**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the most advisable solution would be to add a further `common` module to provide these *common* (indeed) classes.

You would then move from:

```
project
  |_____A
  |_____B

A (containing class C1 and C2) ---> B
B ----> (C1 and C2) via A           
          |_________________not possible, cyclic dependency !!
```

To the following:

```
project
  |_____A-module
  |_____B-module
  |_____common-module (C1, C2 classes)

A (without C1 and C2) ---> B
B ----> (C1 and C2) via common
          |_________________ now possible, no cyclic dependency any longer
```

A would hence transitively depend also on common (but you can also make it explicit, if you prefer).

To make it more clear in a tree view, you would hence have:

```
common
  ├─ B
     └─ A
```

Doing so you would also improve future changes, maintenability and testing, providing a better separation of concerns, that is, the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) applied at module level.